# Create a second homegroup on same network

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, home-networking, homegroup

My network has a homegroup set already in one PC, but I do not want to use that. I want to create my own HomeGroup since I don't have access to that PC. I tried doing it from control panel and Settings charm, but all I see is just an option to join existing homegroup not to create another one. Any idea how to create a second homegroup?

Answer (score 1):

[This Microsoft page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/homegroup-help#homegroup-start-to-finish=windows-81&v1h=win81tab2&v2h=win7tab1) provides a comprehensive guide on how to create a homegroup in Winodws 8

> 1. Open HomeGroup by swiping in from the right edge of the screen,
>      tapping Settings (or if you're using a mouse, pointing to the
>      lower-right corner of the screen, moving the mouse pointer up, and
>      then clicking Settings), tapping or clicking Change PC settings,
>      tapping or click Network, and then tapping or clicking HomeGroup.
> 2. Tap or click Create.
> 3. Select the libraries and devices that you want to share with the
>      homegroup.
>
> Note: If a homegroup already exists on your network, you'll be asked to join it instead of creating a new one.

To work around that limitation try following steps (for Windows 7):

> 1. Go to Network and sharing center. Change network type from Home to Public. Click Close.
> 2. Click "Change Advanced sharing settings". Click OK or Cancel.
> 3. Change network type back to "Home" and then press Next.
> 4. After this you may create a a new Homegroup automatically.

For Windows 8 this does not seem to be possible. Please read [this discussion](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/how-to-create-multiple-homegroup-accounts-on/b4418b4c-bf04-430e-bf7c-c538cb0e7682) on Microsoft forums. As you can see Windows is getting better and better with every version.

Comment: Yeah I tried it. All it says is to join that existing homegroup. I want to create another and connect on that, since the existing homegroup is made by a pc which I don't have access to.

Comment: I have updated my post ^^

Comment: Can you connect to another network or remove that computer with the homegroup from the network?  If your computer doesn't sense another homegroupnit should give you an option to create one.